# How to include types coming from private internal packages in the final build of a react lib with Vite?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, rollup, monorepo

When I try to build my react lib using vite, I'm having the declaration file which is not including type definitions coming from my internal package.

I had this monorepo setup:

```
packages
   internal
   my-react-lib
```

some files in my-react-lib are importing and exporting types from internal package

the idea is to have it available in the final declaration file, but the result is that vite is creating the file like a import instead of copy the whole type definition, like this:

actual declaration file:

```
import { InternalType } from "@packages/internal"
export { InternalType }
```

this is a problem because @packages/internal only exists when is in develop mode, when I build my react library I need to place the whole type definition coming from @package/internal

what aditional field should I add in vite.config.js or tsconfig.json?

expected declaration file:

```
export interface InternalType {
   foo: bar
}
```

Comment: do you have `"declaration:" true` in your tsconfig in the tsconfig.json for the library? if so, it should output a .d.ts file for the library

Comment: yes, I already have declaration field as true,  the .d.ts file is being generated, but the thing is that internal types are not being defined, are getting imported from a out of scope library because those library are only for internal usage